# having trouble passing multiple dictionaries for the argument record_path in json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas, api, json-normalize

I'm having troubles completely unnesting this json from an Api.

```
[{'id': 1,
  'name': 'Buzz',
  'tagline': 'A Real Bitter Experience.',
  'first_brewed': '09/2007',
  'description': 'A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.',
  'image_url': 'https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png',
  'abv': 4.5,
  'ibu': 60,
  'target_fg': 1010,
  'target_og': 1044,
  'ebc': 20,
  'srm': 10,
  'ph': 4.4,
  'attenuation_level': 75,
  'volume': {'value': 20, 'unit': 'litres'},
  'boil_volume': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'litres'},
  'method': {'mash_temp': [{'temp': {'value': 64, 'unit': 'celsius'},
     'duration': 75}],
   'fermentation': {'temp': {'value': 19, 'unit': 'celsius'}},
   'twist': None},
  'ingredients': {'malt': [{'name': 'Maris Otter Extra Pale',
     'amount': {'value': 3.3, 'unit': 'kilograms'}},
    {'name': 'Caramalt', 'amount': {'value': 0.2, 'unit': 'kilograms'}},
    {'name': 'Munich', 'amount': {'value': 0.4, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}],
   'hops': [{'name': 'Fuggles',
     'amount': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'start',
     'attribute': 'bitter'},
    {'name': 'First Gold',
     'amount': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'start',
     'attribute': 'bitter'},
    {'name': 'Fuggles',
     'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'middle',
     'attribute': 'flavour'},
    {'name': 'First Gold',
     'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'middle',
     'attribute': 'flavour'},
    {'name': 'Cascade',
     'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'end',
     'attribute': 'flavour'}],
   'yeast': 'Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™'},
  'food_pairing': ['Spicy chicken tikka masala',
   'Grilled chicken quesadilla',
   'Caramel toffee cake'],
  'brewers_tips': 'The earthy and floral aromas from the hops can be overpowering. Drop a little Cascade in at the end of the boil to lift the profile with a bit of citrus.',
  'contributed_by': 'Sam Mason <samjbmason>'},
 {'id': 2,
  'name': 'Trashy Blonde',
  'tagline': "You Know You Shouldn't",
  'first_brewed': '04/2008',
  'description': 'A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.',
  'image_url': 'https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png',
  'abv': 4.1,
  'ibu': 41.5,
  'target_fg': 1010,
  'target_og': 1041.7,
  'ebc': 15,
  'srm': 15,
  'ph': 4.4,
  'attenuation_level': 76,
  'volume': {'value': 20, 'unit': 'litres'},
  'boil_volume': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'litres'},
  'method': {'mash_temp': [{'temp': {'value': 69, 'unit': 'celsius'},
     'duration': None}],
   'fermentation': {'temp': {'value': 18, 'unit': 'celsius'}},
   'twist': None},
  'ingredients': {'malt': [{'name': 'Maris Otter Extra Pale',
     'amount': {'value': 3.25, 'unit': 'kilograms'}},
    {'name': 'Caramalt', 'amount': {'value': 0.2, 'unit': 'kilograms'}},
    {'name': 'Munich', 'amount': {'value': 0.4, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}],
   'hops': [{'name': 'Amarillo',
     'amount': {'value': 13.8, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'start',
     'attribute': 'bitter'},
    {'name': 'Simcoe',
     'amount': {'value': 13.8, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'start',
     'attribute': 'bitter'},
    {'name': 'Amarillo',
     'amount': {'value': 26.3, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'end',
     'attribute': 'flavour'},
    {'name': 'Motueka',
     'amount': {'value': 18.8, 'unit': 'grams'},
     'add': 'end',
     'attribute': 'flavour'}],
   'yeast': 'Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™'},
  'food_pairing': ['Fresh crab with lemon',
   'Garlic butter dipping sauce',
   'Goats cheese salad',
   'Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar'],
  'brewers_tips': 'Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.',
  'contributed_by': 'Sam Mason <samjbmason>'}]
```

I was able to unnest it to a level using json_normalize

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers"
requests.get(url).json()
data = requests.get(url).json()
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

[this is an image of the output after using json_normalize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idSxx.png)

now to unnest the column 'method.mash_temp' I included record_path

```
pd.json_normalize(
    data, 
    record_path =['method', 'mash_temp'], 
    meta=['id', 'name']
)
```

but I am having troubles adding the other columns('ingredients.malt', 'ingredients.hops') with list of dictionaries in the record_path argument.

Comment: Would you like to unnest every nested dictionary in the data to columns? Try using explode

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace and/or a more detailed description of the trouble you are having?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I already unnested the dictionaries, I am having issues unnesting the list of dictionaries for multiple columns. I tried using explode like you suggested but it only unlisted the list of dictionaries and did not unnest the dictionaries inside the list also it didn't work for multiple columns

Comment: the problem is that I got data from an api that contains dictionaries and lists of dictionaries. I was able to unnest the dictionaries using ison_normalize but having a difficult time unnesting the list of dictionaries @RodrigoLaguna

Comment: @ayomidealayande what's the expected output, please add expected table